# Map jetty ResourceHandler to a URL

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

Is it possible using embedded Jetty to serve static files from directory X but mapped to URL Y? I have static files stored under directory "web", but I want the URL be something like `http://host/myapp`.

I have already successfully ran a server configured with `ResourceHandler` in the following way:

```java
ResourceHandler ctx = new ResourceHandler();
ctx.setResourceBase("path-to-web");
HandlerList list = new HandlerList();
list.addHandler(ctx);
...
server.setHandler(list);
```

But the result is serving the files under `/web` and not under the desired URL mapping.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The ResourceHandler has no context configurable, but you can simply wrap it in a ContextHandler to achieve that.

Try this instead:

```java
ContextHandler ctx = new ContextHandler("/my-files"); /* the server uri path */
ResourceHandler resHandler = new ResourceHandler();
resHandler.setResourceBase("path-to-web");
ctx.setHandler(resHandler);
server.setHandler(ctx);
```

That will serve `/my-files` as the ResourceHandler content of the filesystem `path-to-web`

Answer (score 2):

The above doesn't work for Jetty 9, but this does:

```
ContextHandler contextHandler = new ContextHandler("/my-files");
contextHandler.setResourceBase("/tmp/static");

ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
contextHandler.setHandler(resourceHandler);

server.setHandler(contextHandler);
```

Comment: this seems not working with jetty 9. Could you provide a link to some doc?

Comment: I have created a separate question for jetty 9 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346438/resourcehandler-stop-hosting-files-with-jetty-9-404-not-found-error-works-fin                                                             Will be glad if you give me a hint