# ResourceHandler stop hosting files with jetty 9 - 404 not found error (works fine with jetty 8)

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

Apparently, `ResourceHandler` stop hosting files with jetty 9 - **404 not found error** (works fine with jetty 8). Here is the code:

```
    ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
    resourceHandler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
    resourceHandler.setResourceBase("some_resource_base");

    HandlerList handlerList = new HandlerList();
    handlerList.setHandlers(new Handler[]{servletHandler, resourceHandler});
    server.setHandler(handlerList);
    server.start();
```

This quistion with the accepted answer does not seem to work against **jetty 9** -  [Serving static files w/ embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284584/serving-static-files-w-embedded-jetty)

Comment: Example incomplete, what's `servletHandler` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `servletHandler` is a `ServletContextHandler`

*(Note: it best not be an actual `ServletHandler`, as that's an internal class, not meant to be instantiated directly)*

Then the `resourceHandler` will never be called, as the `DefaultServlet` processing (or `Default404Servlet`) at the end of the `ServletContextHandler` chain will always respond, not allowing `resourceHandler` to even execute.

If you have a `ServletContextHandler`, do not use `ResourceHandler` use the `DefaultServlet` in that `ServletContextHandler` to setup and serve your static files.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Hopefully, it will help a others on this thread too.. Thanks Joakim. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207477/serving-static-files-from-alternate-path-in-embedded-jetty/20223103#20223103

Answer (score 4):

In case somebody is looking for a working example, this is how I combined a ResourceHandler with a ContextHandler (partially based on current Jetty docs: [Jetty documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/resource-handler.html))

```
        srv = new Server();
        ServerConnector srvConn = new ServerConnector(srv);
        srvConn.setHost("localhost");
        srvConn.setPort(8080);
        srvConn.setIdleTimeout(30000);
        srv.addConnector(srvConn);
        //used for webSocket comm later:
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");

        //for static  content:
        ResourceHandler resH = new ResourceHandler();
        resH.setDirectoriesListed(true);
        resH.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "index.html" });
        resH.setResourceBase("./my/web/root");
        ContextHandler resCtx = new ContextHandler();
        resCtx.setHandler(resH);

        //Add both ContextHandlers to server:
        ContextHandlerCollection handlers = new ContextHandlerCollection(resCtx, context);
        srv.setHandler(handlers);
```