# jetty 9 serving HTML file PWC6117: File not found

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jetty, web.xml

I use jetty in my spring app. After migrating from Jetty 8 to Jetty 9 (replacing SelectChannelConnector with ServerConnector) I'm left with 404 error code after navigating to main website address (spring security redirects me to /login) and log:

*ERROR: PWC6117: File "/Users/jonny/projects/mypro/modules/backoffice/src/main/webapp/login" not found*

it looks like jetty 9 doesn't honor web.xml file?, which is in my case

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/login.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and my configuration of WebApp object is:

```
Server server = new Server(); 

WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
webapp.setContextPath(path);
webapp.setDescriptor("*src/main/webapp*/WEB-INF/web.xml");
webapp.setBaseResource(new ResourceCollection("*src/main/webapp*"));

HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
connector.setPort(*port*);
server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{connector});
handlers.addHandler(webApp);
server.setHandler(handlers);
server.start();
server.join();
```

I wish that `/login` served `login.jsp`, how to do that?

**But the body of `login.jsp` is pure html and all I want is to serve it from `/login` context**

Old:
While searching for a hint I red:

- [Map jetty ResourceHandler to a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958251/map-jetty-resourcehandler-to-a-url?lq=1)
- [ResourceHandler stop hosting files with jetty 9 - 404 not found error (works fine with jetty 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346438/resourcehandler-stop-hosting-files-with-jetty-9-404-not-found-error-works-fin)
- [Serving static files w/ embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284584/serving-static-files-w-embedded-jetty?lq=1)

but still don't know how to properly setup jetty with `web.xml`, any ideas?

Comment: partial solution is to re-write login.jsp to  login servlet and instead of `jsp-file` add `servlet-class` and that would work fine, but this is rather unpleasant and I wish to have jsp file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that code snippet represents how you are initializing your webapp, then you are missing **a lot** of JSP initialization steps.

There's an example project produced by the Jetty Project showing how to use JSP with embedded Jetty at

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp

Pay attention to ...

- The required ClassLoader type
- The scratchDir declaration
- The ServletContainerInitializer setup
- The Jsp Servlet Holder and mappings
- The InstanceManager

(just to name a few big ones)

Comment: Hi again, I've changed a little my question, it's .jsp file only to serve html (in jetty8 it was ok). I've added mine resource handler but that completely doesn't work in case when I pack everything into fatjar

<code>ResourceHandler resHandler = new ResourceHandler();
resHandler.setResourceBase("/path/to/login.jsp");
ContextHandler ctx = new ContextHandler("/login");
ctx.setHandler(resHandler);</code>

Comment: [Do not mix ResourceHandler and ServletContextHandler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28419106/775715) (in fact, don't use ResourceHandler, at all, there is no advantage to using it over the DefaultServlet)