# What is difference between ServletContextHandler.setResourceBase and ResourceHandler.setResourceBase when using Jetty embedded container?

Tags: java, jetty

I'm using embedded Jetty to create a static web site. Does ServletContextHandler.setResourceBase("...") have a same effect as ResourceHandler.setResourceBase("...")?

Example:

```
// ServletContextHandler case
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setResourceBase("/tmp/...");
// ResourceHandler case
ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
resourceHandler.setResourceBase("/tmp/...");
```

I have tried test both of them. ResourceHandler works exactly what I want. But otherwise doesn't. What's the difference between them?

(Sorry for my poor English :P)

#### Update

After changed, below is whole code. Context("/") serves static files, wsContext("/ws") serves web socket endpoints. Of course Context("/") is able to serve web socket endpoints as well.

```
 server = new Server();
 server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
 ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
 connector.setPort(8000);
 server.addConnector(connector);

 // Setup the basic application "context" for this application at "/"
 // This is also known as the handler tree (in jetty speak)
 ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

 context.setContextPath("/");
 context.setResourceBase(System.getProperty("webapp.path"));

 ServletContextHandler wsContext = new ServletContextHandler();
 wsContext.setContextPath("/ws");

 ContextHandlerCollection contexts=new ContextHandlerCollection();
 contexts.setHandlers(new Handler[]{context, wsContext});

 server.setHandler(contexts);

 context.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/");

 // Initialize javax.websocket layer
 ServerContainer wsContainer = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(wsContext);

 // Add WebSocket endpoint to javax.websocket layer
 // code omitted...

 server.start();
 logger.info("WebServer started.");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With that setup, the `resourceHandler` will never be called, as the `DefaultServlet` processing (or `Default404Servlet`) at the end of the `ServletContextHandler` chain will always respond, not allowing `resourceHandler` to even execute.

If you have a `ServletContextHandler`, do not use `ResourceHandler` use the `DefaultServlet` in that `ServletContextHandler` to setup and serve your static files.

`ResourceHandler` is very simplistic, if you want more control / features, use a `DefaultServlet` configured in your `ServletContextHandler` instead.

Ok, with that out of the way ...

The [`ServletContextHandler.setBaseResource(Resource)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler.html#setBaseResource-org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource-) is the place for the `ServletContext` itself to configure its context-wide `resourceBase`.

(Note: the parameter of setResourceBase() is a URL string that can point to a `file://` directory or even a `jar:file://` location.  Pretty much anything supported by [`Resource.newResource(String)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/resource/Resource.html#newResource-java.lang.String-))

- `${resourceBase}/` is the lookup point for various methods in [`javax.servlet.ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html?is-external=true) such as:

  - `String getRealPath(String path)`
  - `URL getResource(String path)`
  - `InputStream getResourceAsStream(String path)`
  - `Set<String> getResources(String path)`
- Requested resources that don't match any of your servlets or filters, will then be handled by the `DefaultServlet`, which might serve static resources (such as `*.html`, `*.css`, `*.js`) from the specified `${resourceBase}/${request.pathInfo}`

`ResourceHandler` does not participate in `ServletContextHandler` is an is inappropriate to mix with `ServletContextHandler`.

Also, don't forget to set `ServletContextHandler.setContextPath(String)` to your desired context path (usually `"/"`)

And yes, you can even have [multiple `DefaultServlet` configurations in a single `ServletContextHandler`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207477/jetty-embedded-file-server-servlet/20223103#20223103).

Comment: Why is it important to set the context path?